# How to compute a discrete histogram of a list

Tags: list-manipulation, functions, histograms

I'm trying to compute the discrete histogram of a set of values.

By histogram I mean the absolute frequency a value appears on the dataset, by discrete I mean the values are from a discrete set, e.g. integers.

Example: given `data = {1,4,1,2,3,1,4}`, I would like to have an efficient way of obtaining something like

```
{{1,3}, {2,1}, {3,1}, {4,2}}
```

I Tried using BinCount and HistogramList, but both are more suitable for continuous values.

My current solution is to use `Count` along with `DeleteDuplicates`:

```
{#, Count[data, #]} & /@ DeleteDuplicates[data]
```

My question is: do you know any more efficient way (without using procedural programming)?

I ask this because if there are N elements from which M are distinct, this approach requires M sweeps on a dataset of size N (M calls of Count), which is not required for the outcome I'm searching for: this operation should be feasible in one sweep.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you are looking for [`Tally`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Tally.html?q=Tally&lang=en).

```
data = {1, 4, 1, 2, 3, 1, 4};
Tally[data]

(* {{1, 3}, {4, 2}, {2, 1}, {3, 1}} *)
```

As you can see from the timings, `Tally` is vastly superior. I believe this will be the case regardless what form the data takes.

```
data = RandomChoice[Range[10], 10^7];

AbsoluteTiming[r1 = {#, Count[data, #]} & /@ DeleteDuplicates[data];]
(* {4.321247, Null} *)

AbsoluteTiming[r2 = Tally[data];]
(* {0.017001, Null} *)

r1 == r2
(*True*)
```

Comment: That was exactly the function I was searching. The name couldn't be more easy to find... anyway, thank you, very useful answer.