# Count the elements of a list of two-element sets

Tags: list-manipulation, functions

I have a problem with counting the cardinality. I have a list of two-element sets

```
S = {{3.,0.0425}, {3.,0.423}, {3.1, 0.044}, {3.2, 0.567}, {3.2, 0.599}, {3.2, 0.52313}}
```

I would like to get a list:

```
O = {{3,2}, {3.1,1}, {3.2,3}}
```

I mean that I would like to get a list that counts the sets with the same first element.

Comment: I would suggest: Tally[S[[All, 1]]]

Comment: at least closely related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/30859/5478